# What intuition led to J. Wang and X.G. Wen's lattice formulation of the 3450 chiral gauge theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, quantum-anomalies, chirality, lattice-gauge-theory

In the paper cited below, Juven Wang and Xiao-Gang Wen give an example of a lattice model that reduces to a chiral $U(1)$ gauge theory at low energy. The low energy theory is called the $3450$ model. The lattice model is remarkable because the gauged $U(1)$ symmetry is on site (in contrast to the Ginsparg-Wilson approach), and the would-be doublers are eliminated instead by a clever choice of interaction terms between the lattice fermions.

The lattice model itself is easy enough to write down (see below), but the fact that it has the desired low-energy limit is not obvious at all. The authors found a way to show that it works, but the argument is complex, which makes me think they must have had some prior intuition to suggest that the lattice model shown below would probably work.

What was that intuition?

I'll describe the lattice model so I can make my question more specific. The model lives in two-dimensional spacetime, with continuous time and discrete space. I'll write the fermion annihilation operators as $c_n(k)$, where $k$ is a lattice site. The subscript $n\in\{3,4,5,0\}$ indicates how the fermion transforms under the $U(1)$ symmetry: $c_n(k)\to \exp( i\,n\theta)c_n(k)$. The Hamiltonian without the gauge field is
\begin{align}
\newcommand{\dc}{c^\dagger}
 H 
 &\sim \sum_k\big(
   \dc_3(k) c_3(k+1)
  +\dc_4(k) c_4(k+1)
  -\dc_5(k) c_5(k+1)
  -\dc_0(k) c_0(k+1)\big)
\\
 &+ 
 \sum_{ab} \alpha_{ab} \sum_k
  \tilde c^\dagger_a(k) \tilde c_a(k)
  \tilde c^\dagger_b(k) \tilde c_b(k)
\\
 &+ 
 \beta \sum_k 
  \tilde c_3(k)
  \big(\tilde c_4(k)\tilde c_4(k+1)\big)^\dagger
  \tilde c_5(k)
  \big(\tilde c_0(k)\tilde c_0(k+1)\big)
\\
 &+ 
 \gamma \sum_k 
 \big(\tilde c_3(k-1)
  \tilde c_3(k)
  \tilde c_3(k+1)\big)^\dagger
  \tilde c_4(k)
  \tilde c_5(k)
  \big(\tilde c_0(k-1)
   \tilde c_0(k)
   \tilde c_0(k+1)\big)^\dagger
\\
 &+\text{hermitian conjugate},
\end{align}
where $\tilde c_n(k)=\sum_j f(k-j)c_n(j)$ for a smearing function $f$ chosen so that the $\tilde c$ involve only the would-be doublers. This has an on-site $U(1)$ symmetry, and the pattern of charges is dictated by the products in the third and fourth terms: those terms are invariant only if the charges of the four fermion species are proportional to $3,4,5,0$. Since the $U(1)$ symmetry is on-site, a background gauge field can be added using ordinary link variables. According to the paper, as suggested by the signs on the first line (the kinetic term), the low-energy effective theory turns out to have two left-handed fermions with charges $3$ and $4$ and two right-handed fermions with charges $5$ and $0$, at least for a special choice of coefficients in the second term. The result is a chiral gauge theory satisfying the two-dimensional version of the anomaly cancellation condition: $3^2+4^2=5^2+0^2$.

My specific question is: Would this work for *any* choice of interaction terms that involves only $\tilde c$ and that dictates the $3,4,5,0$ pattern of charges? Or is there some intuition behind the other details of the interaction terms?

---

**Reference:** Juven Wang and Xiao-Gang Wen (2019), "Solution to the $1+1$ dimensional gauge chiral Fermion problem," *Physical Review D* **99**:111501 (https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.99.111501 or https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.05998)

Comment: Have you looked at this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.7480, it is their prior work. And are you familiar with the gapping conditions (say p.17 and Appendix E)? These are very well-known facts in condensed matter physics, almost every serious graduate student who studies fractional quantum Hall effect would know.

Comment: >>My specific question is: Would this work for any choice of interaction terms that involves only ̃  and that dictates the 3,4,5,0 pattern of charges? Or is there some intuition behind the other details of the interaction terms? **Answer:** Obviously their paper proves that for any U(1) anomaly-free theory (chiral or non-chiral U(1) symmetry or not), they can show the 't Hooft anomaly-free condition is "dual" equivalent to the gapping rules that can gap the chiral fermions. So it is not just for 3-4-5-0, it is for any anomaly-free theory.

Comment: Here "dual" equivalent means a transformation mapping in the U(1)$^n$ (Narain) charge lattice.

Comment: Since 2017, this phenomenon is also called *symmetric mass generation* ([arXiv:1705.09313](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.09313)). The preprint [arXiv:2204.14271](https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.14271) gives a nice review.